# Ionic Angular SSR on Apache Server?

Tags: angular, apache, ionic-framework, server-side-rendering, ionic5

Is there any way to implement Ionic Angular SSR on an apache server? Im hosting a PWA.
If not, what server implementation do you recommend? Any hint would help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into NGINX or a NodeJS server to run the actual Angular Universal. More information about all this can be found in the Angular docs as well: https://angular.io/guide/universal.

Hopefully this will help you in search for a hosting.